# How to short the code to change control properties on command buttion click in ms-access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a userform with a group of command buttons with similiar properties and fuctionality. I am using these buttons to let the user keep track about his activity. So e.g. whenever user will click the "production" button the application label will say "production" mode, when the user presses "Break" button the label will change from "production" mode to "Break" mode, Similiarly I have 7-8 buttons altogether on same form. Other conditions are whichever buttons gets pressed that button should get disabled and all other buttons should get enabled, followed by next button, if pressed it should get disabled and it should enable the button which was pressed previously.

The button which has been pressed whould also change its color and should also change the previous button's color back to normal.

I understand it would be difficult to understand the scenario, please check the code below for one of my buttons and its working well.

```
Private Sub btn1()
    Me.Label78.Caption = Me.btn1.Caption
    Me.btn1.BackColor = RGB(250, 100, 100)
    Me.btn1.Gradient = 12
    Me.btn1.Enabled = False
    Me.btn2.Enabled = True
    Me.btn2.BackColor = RGB(100, 250, 100)
    Me.btn2.Gradient = 12
    Me.btn3.Enabled = True
    Me.btn3.BackColor = RGB(100, 250, 100)
    Me.btn3.Gradient = 12
End Sub
```

the above code works perfeclty and changes properties to 3 buttons(its sample code not the code for all 7 buttons),  but I have total 7-8 button and i may add more buttons in future SO if i keep on writing this kind of code in one button for all 7-8 buttons, then it will take a lot of time and efforct.

So what is the best possible way to short this code ?

I know this is little complicated hence please ask if any more information required.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a helper subfunction:

```
Private Sub SetButton(ByVal ButtonId As Long, ByVal Enabled As Boolean)

    Dim BackColor As Long

    If Enabled Then
        BackColor = RGB(100, 250, 100)
    Else
        BackColor = RGB(250, 100, 100)
    End If

    With Me("btn" & Cstr(Id))
        .Enabled = Enabled
        .Gradient = 12
        .BackColor = BackColor
    End With

End Sub
```

Then call this in the *OnClick* event like:

```
For Id = 1 To 8
    Select Case Id
        Case 1, 2, 4, 7
            SetButton Id, True
        Case Else
            SetButton Id, False
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, its a great idea. However, before I implement this, I just wanty to clear some of my doubts with your code. Wolud i need to use the onclick event code on every button, & why do we have case 1,2, 4, 7 only. It would really nice if you can explain it a bit, I am just new to VBA

Comment: You will need to call the function for all buttons that interact with the others. The Select Case is an example only; you will have to adjust to your actual form and buttons - which only you know about.